# FieldName for Field Controls added to a Page Layout in SharePoint Designer 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, page-layout, field-controls

In SharePoint Designer 2010, when I drag a field from the toolbox onto a page layout the generated field control uses the field ID for the FieldName attribute.

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="f55c4d88-1f2e-4ad9-aaa8-819af4ee7ee8" 
    runat="server">
</PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField>
```

Is there some way to get SharePoint Designer to use the field's internal name instead?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible (unless someone else corrects me, hence a comment and not an answer), and this is another one of the reasons why I never use the visual designer in SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Rob, What happens when you replace the FieldName="[Guid]" with FieldName="[InternalFieldName]" - I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Simon: Using the internal field name is not the issue. I was asking if I could configure SPD to include the internal field name instead of the GUID when it generates the markup for the field control.

Answer (score 3):

Hi Rob: I don't know why Microsoft changed this from 2007 functionality, but it does seem to be the case in 2010 that it uses the GUID, which, IMHO, adds some extra work to creating page layouts, especially if you're porting changes from one site to another where columns potentially have different GUIDs.  Who knows why, but I haven't figured out how to change SPD to use Field Names and is something I've got used to now.  I can see problems with using GUIDs, so I always change to the internal name.  Sorry it's not much of an answer.

Comment: It might not be much of an answer, but sometimes it might be the only answer.